# python objects taking previous objects attributes from the wrong text files as well as their own from the right text files

Tags: python, algorithm, class, object, text-files

I am trying to load data from text files into my python objects of a class. When I run the code however, each object gets all the data loaded from previous text files loaded into its attributes and I don't know how this is happening. I would be very grateful for some help, thanks.

```
class Cocktail:

    recipe = []
    categories = []
    line = ''
    line2 = ''
    character = []
    name = ''
    path = ''

    def __init__(self):
        cocktails.append(self)
        #self.name = name

    def define(self, name):
        #print(self.name)
        self.name = name #the name of the cocktail is taken from a master text file
        self.path = self.name + '.txt' #each object will be linked to an individual text file containing its data
        with open(self.path, 'r') as cocktail_data: #opening the specific text file
            for line in cocktail_data:
                self.character = line.split(' ', 1)
                if self.character[0] == '#': #if the line starts with a # 
                    self.line = line.strip('#')
                    self.line2 = self.line.strip('/n')
                    self.categories.append(self.line2) #loads that lines data into the objects 'categories list'

                elif line.strip() == 'recipe': #when the recipe part of the text file is reached
                    break
            for line in cocktail_data: #continuing through the document 
                self.recipe.append(line.strip()) #adds each line of the rest of the document to the object's 'recipe' attribute

    def print(self): #for testing
        print(self.name) #prints the name of that cocktail that the object represents
        print(self.categories) #prints all the categories for that object
        print(self.recipe) #prints the recipe list for that object
        print('end') 
        #each new object seems to have the values (for its categories and recipe attributes) for all previous objects as well as its own
cocktails = []

with open('master.txt') as input_data:
    for line in input_data:
        name = line.strip() #the string that is the current line on the master text file
        cocktail = Cocktail() #creates object of Cocktail for each name in master document
        cocktail.define(name)
        cocktail.print()
```

This is what is my python shell displays:

```
cocktail1

[' a\n', ' b\n', ' c\n', ' d\n']

['one', 'two', 'three', 'end']

end

cocktail2

[' a\n', ' b\n', ' c\n', ' d\n', ' aq\n', ' bq\n', ' cq\n', ' dq\n']

['one', 'two', 'three', 'end', 'one q', 'two q', 'threeq', 'endq']

end

cocktail3

[' a\n', ' b\n', ' c\n', ' d\n', ' aq\n', ' bq\n', ' cq\n', ' dq\n', ' aw\n', ' bw\n', ' cw\n', ' dw\n']

['one', 'two', 'three', 'end', 'one q', 'two q', 'threeq', 'endq', 'onew', 'two w', 'threew', 'endw']

end
```

cocktail1 should not have any with a 'q' or 'w' at the end, cocktail 2 should only have the ones with a 'q' at the end and cocktail 3 should only have the ones with a 'w' at the end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably are used to Java or other OO languages where the instance attributes are declared in the class body - and you are trying to do the same here with:

```
class Cocktail:

    recipe = []
    categories = []
    line = ''
    line2 = ''
    character = []
    name = ''
    path = ''

    def __init__(self):
        cocktails.append(self)
        #self.name = name
```

In Python however, any declaration in the class body if for a *class* attribute. Instance attributes are set directly on the instance (inside methods using the `self.attrname = value`  type of statement)

For some of the attributes above you won't see the problem, since you use immutable objects, and just shadow the class attributes when you set them in the instance  - like when you do `self.name = name` - you create a new `name` attribute on that instance alone.

However, when you do `self.categories.append(...)` you are modifying the single `categories` object (a list) which is defined in the cocktail class, and is accessed by all cocktail objects.

To fix your behavior, just declare your instance attributes as such - doing this, for example:

```
class Cocktail:
    def __init__(self):
        self.recipe = []
        self.categories = []
        self.line = ''
        self.line2 = ''
        self.character = []
        self.name = ''
        self.path = ''
```

(but keep in mind you don't have to declare a variable or attribute in Python before you need to set its value at runtime  - you can just set them in the methods you need to - the only ones you need to actually create are the ones containing lists, since you want to append values to those).